# Drainage pipe with sock or without sock behind retaining wall?

Tags: walls, drainage

I am building a 4ft retaining wall that is 65ft long and the soil I have is sandy, I live in NM, I'm going to bury a 4in corregated perforated pipe but I don't know if it should have a sock on it or not? I am going to be putting 3/4in gravel on top of it, and it will have weep holes through the wall. If anyone can help me out, I would appreciate it.

Comment: What's the soil outside the "clean stone"? that's what you have to stop, and preferably before it gets into your stone, not just when it reaches the pipe/sock. Corrugated drain pipe is almost always the wrong choice - it's very hard to get installed at a proper slope, and it guaranteed to catch a load of crap in the corrugations anyway. Rigid drain pipe can be set at a proper slope and will drain clean if that's done and the holes are correctly placed down (there are two rows and they go either side of straight down.)

Comment: The soil is a very sandy soil, more like powder sand, but when it gets wet, it hardens like a rock.  So, I'm still confused on whether to use one with or without a sock?

Comment: It's not necessary to sock your pipe if it'll be surrounded by clean gravel, but it is necessary to "sock" your gravel, i.e. filter fabric between any soil and stone.

Comment: "3/4 gravel out clean stone" I think `out` is a typo. please [edit] to correct. If not, please edit to clarify

Comment: I read that if you have a sheet of filter fabric in between the soil and gravel, the filter fabric gets clogged and then starts to put pressure on the wall? I noticed some people put filter fabric, and some don't?

Answer (score 2):

If your soil is of a type that will tend to clog pipes, what you really want is filter fabric "boxed" all around your stone around your pipe, not a sock around your pipe. The boxed stone has a much larger surface area for water to weep through, (which is important because said weeping will be slow, if the soil is of a plugging type and the fabric is effective at stopping it) and will keep the stone open - the sock is smaller, and the stone will fill up with soil, limiting water access to the socked pipe.

Comment: The soil is a very sandy soil, more like powder sand, but when it gets wet, it hardens like a rock. I'm not sure if it will clog the pipes or not?  So, I'm still confused on whether to use one with or without a sock? I understand "box" around gravel and pipe, but I don't want hydrostatic pressure pushing on the soil and the fabric up against the the gravel and then the wall.

Comment: @Michael you need a filter fabric suitable for the type of soil. The box is filled with gravel/stone, and the fabric is around the box (as written in the answer) to provide a large weeping surface. Due to the fill there will be no hydrostatic pressure differential at the box surfaces.